# Javascript: array in function, undefined single element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this function:

```
function toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i) {
console.log(lines_agenti); //the console show the array
console.log(lines_agenti[i]); //the console show me undefined

    if (!lines_agenti[i].getVisible()) {
        lines_agenti[i].setVisible(true);
        visible = true;
    } else {
        lines_agenti[i].setVisible(false);
        visible = false;
    }
return visible;
```

}

Like you can see in the code, the first "console.log" show me the content of the array, but the second one give me undefined.

Obviously the following code in the function doesn't work.

Here is where I call the function

```
checkbox.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      visible = toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i);
      if(visible == true){
          //do stuff
      }else{
          //do stuff
      }
  })(i));
```

This one is inside another function where I create the checkboxs with DOM.

The array "lines_agenti" is defined like global variable at the beginning:

```
<script> 
  var lines_agenti = [];
  [...]
```

Can you help me? Thank you a lot.

I attached a screen of the console.[image: console]

Comment: Um, do you know what `i` is?

Comment: "i" is the count variable of a for that contain "checkbox.addEventListener".
If I put console.log(i) inside the function "toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i)", it gives to me correctly "0" at the first iteration

Comment: Is there no typo there? You defined `lines_agente` at the top and refer to it as `lines_agenti`

Comment: DO you realize you are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the click. You are NOT calling the function on click.

Comment: sorry, typing error.. it's var lines_agenti = [];

Comment: You are registering an IIFE to the addEventListener, try just by using a function definition without executing it immediately.

Comment: Yes, I understand my error. I have different checkboxes. 
For each of them, i want assign the function "toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo" that make stuff on a single element of the array "lines_agenti".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here

```
checkbox.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
  console.log(i);
  visible = toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i);
  if(visible == true){
      //do stuff
  }else{
      //do stuff
  }
})(i));
```

is basically doing this:

```
(function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      visible = toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i);
      if(visible == true){
          //do stuff
      }else{
          //do stuff
      }
})(i)
checkbox.addEventListener('click', undefined);
```

You are running the function and assigning what it returns to the function. You are not calling the function onclick. One way to solve it is to to return a function

```
checkbox.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
  return function () {
      console.log(i);
      visible = toggleAgenteMarkerSingolo(i);
      if(visible == true){
          //do stuff
      }else{
          //do stuff
      }
  }
})(i));
```

Comment: Yes.. That was the problem. Thanks a lot! 
Do you have some links where can I master this sort of problems??